# How to add a button to show the result in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

The user will enter a number on the input field then will select one of the radio buttons
the result will appear dynamically if he press on any key but I want to add a button so the user can click it to see the result

```js
$(document).ready(function check() {
$('input').keyup(function check() {

var arg1 = parseFloat($('#in1').val());
var arg2 = parseFloat($('#in2').val());

month=f.m.value
if(month=="10")
$('#tdin1').html(parseInt(((arg1 + (((arg1 * 12) )/ 12))/ month)));
else if (month=="20")
$('#tdin1').html(parseInt(((arg1 + (((arg1 * 18) )/ 12))/ month)));
    
document.getElementById("tdin1").innerHTML = val; 

slider.oninput = function check() {
output.innerHTML = this.value;} });});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="number" id="in1"/>
    
<form name="f">  
<input type="radio" name="m" value="10" onchange="check()">    
<input type="radio" name="m" value="20" onchange="check()">  
</form>
        
<span id="tdin1"></span>
```

Comment: You have most of the code you need. All you need to do now is instead of updating the HTML with the result at keyup events, save the value in a global variable or Indexed DB. Do this for both inputs and all radio selectors. Finally, add a button which has an event handler that checks for all the values entered and display them on the page. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="f">  
<input type="radio" name="m" value="10" onchange="check()">    
<input type="radio" name="m" value="20" onchange="check()">
<input type="button" onclick()="yourfunction()"
</form>
```

Simply add this input type= button and apply the fuction on click it will show the result. you need to make a function and in that function perform operation

Answer (score 0):

Add the button to html and add on click function

```
<form name="f">  
   <input type="radio" name="m" value="10" onchange="check()">    
   <input type="radio" name="m" value="20" onchange="check()">
   <input type="button" onclick="Result()">Result</input>
 </form>
```

add Result() function and render to span tag

```
 <script>

    function Result() {
    document.getElementById("tdin1").innerHTML = val;    
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: can you post the link of your full code  and where you place this code in html file with script tag or separate file for js?